# Dubai Transit (DXB) - Do you need to install DXB Smart App?

Tags: covid-19, dubai, dxb

Do you need to install DXB Smart App for transiting through DXB airport? I installed it anyway on iOS and tried to register but it hangs at "Please wait" and then just does nothing.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you think it might be required?

Answer (score 2):

The app seems to just be a way to get information on the covid situation in Dubai, and contact the local health authorities if necessary.

Are you required to use the app? It's hard to prove a negative, but I see no evidence. Beyond the fact that it would prevent anybody transiting who, for example, doesn't own a smartphone:

Absolutely nothing on the airport's [info page for connecting passengers](https://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections) suggests the app is required for passengers transiting through Dubai airport. The app has been available since at least April 2020, so it seems safe to assume that a major airport like Dubai would have updated the information by now if use of this app were in any way required.

The app's pages on the app stores for [Apple](https://apps.apple.com/ae/app/covid19-dxb-smart-app/id1504818399) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ae.gov.dha.covid19&hl=en&gl=US) devices don't suggest it's required, either.

Answer (score 0):

Cell phone ownership is not yet mandatory, so clearly *NO*, you are not required to have the app installed.